# Can anyone help me get 100% code coverage with this code? Simply checking whether the function has been called will also do

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have no idea how to access the remaining line of code. I simply need to get a full code coverage. Checking if the function has been called (toHaveBeenCalled() ) will also do.

Pasting in the TypeScript file and my Spec file. My current code-coverage is as follows:

TOTAL: 2 FAILED, 3 SUCCESS

================== Coverage summary ==================

Statements   : 30.34% (27/89)

Branches     : 0% (0/22)

Functions    : 26.92% (7/26)

Lines        : 29.07% (25/86)

=====================================================

**update-notification.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { NotificationService } from '../notification.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-notification',
  templateUrl: './update-notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-notification.component.scss']
})
export class UpdateNotificationComponent implements OnInit {
  notificationId: any;
  notificationDetails: any;
  parentNotifications: any[];
  editorInstance = ClassicEditor;
  ckEditorConfig = {
    placeholder: 'Add notification description'
  }
  editNotificationGroup = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    parentNotification: new FormControl(),
    description: new FormControl()
  })
  constructor(
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public notificationService: NotificationService,
    private router: Router,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getParentNotificationsForDropdown();
    this.notificationId = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params.id;
    this.notificationService.getNotificationDetailsById(this.notificationId).
      subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.notificationDetails = res[0];
        this.editNotificationGroup.get('title').setValue(this.notificationDetails.notification_title);
        this.editNotificationGroup.get('description').setValue(this.notificationDetails.notification_message);
        this.editNotificationGroup.get('parentNotification').setValue(this.notificationDetails.linked_notification_id);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.editNotificationGroup.get('title').setValue('title');
        this.editNotificationGroup.get('description').setValue('<strong>desc</strong> of test');
        this.editNotificationGroup.get('parentNotification').setValue('null');
      })
  }
  getParentNotificationsForDropdown() {
    this.notificationService.getTradeNotifications().
      subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.parentNotifications = res;
      }, error => {
        console.log('get parent notifications failed', error);
      })
  }

  submitEditNotification() {
    this.notificationService.updatedNotification(this.editNotificationGroup.value, this.notificationId).
      subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.toastr.success('Notification updated successfully', 'Notification Blast');
        this.router.navigate(['notifications/list']);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  // if 400 then show error on popup, or else something went wrong or redirect on page

}
```

My test cases..

**update-notificatoin.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationService } from '../notification.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ClassicEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { UpdateNotificationComponent } from './update-notification.component';

describe('UpdateNotificationComponent', () => {
  let component: UpdateNotificationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UpdateNotificationComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const notificationServiceStub = () => ({
      getNotificationDetailsById: notificationId => ({ subscribe: f => f({}) }),
      getTradeNotifications: () => ({ subscribe: f => f({}) }),
      updatedNotification: (value, notificationId) => ({
        subscribe: f => f({})
      })
    });
    const activatedRouteStub = () => ({ snapshot: { params: { id: {} } } });
    const routerStub = () => ({ navigate: array => ({}) });
    const toastrServiceStub = () => ({ success: (string, string1) => ({}) });
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [UpdateNotificationComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: NotificationService, useFactory: notificationServiceStub },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useFactory: activatedRouteStub },
        { provide: Router, useFactory: routerStub },
        { provide: ToastrService, useFactory: toastrServiceStub }
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UpdateNotificationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('can load instance', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`editorInstance has default value`, () => {
    expect(component.editorInstance).toEqual(ClassicEditor);
  });

  describe('ngOnInit', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
      const notificationServiceStub: NotificationService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
        NotificationService
      );
      spyOn(component, 'getParentNotificationsForDropdown').and.callThrough();
      spyOn(
        notificationServiceStub,
        'getNotificationDetailsById'
      ).and.callThrough();
      component.ngOnInit();
      expect(component.getParentNotificationsForDropdown).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(
        notificationServiceStub.getNotificationDetailsById
      ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

  describe('getParentNotificationsForDropdown', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
      const notificationServiceStub: NotificationService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
        NotificationService
      );
      spyOn(notificationServiceStub, 'getTradeNotifications').and.callThrough();
      component.getParentNotificationsForDropdown();
      expect(notificationServiceStub.getTradeNotifications).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

  describe('submitEditNotification', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
      const notificationServiceStub: NotificationService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
        NotificationService
      );
      const routerStub: Router = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Router);
      const toastrServiceStub: ToastrService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
        ToastrService
      );
      spyOn(notificationServiceStub, 'updatedNotification').and.callThrough();
      spyOn(routerStub, 'navigate').and.callThrough();
      spyOn(toastrServiceStub, 'success').and.callThrough();
      component.submitEditNotification();
      expect(notificationServiceStub.updatedNotification).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(routerStub.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(toastrServiceStub.success).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the error cases, you need to force the return of an observable that fails.
In your tests, you are always spying on your method (which is good) but calling through.

```js
import {
  throwError
} from 'rxjs';

// In your test

it('should test the error', () => {

  spyOn(
    notificationServiceStub,
    'getNotificationDetailsById'
  ).and.returnValue(throwError('YOUR ERROR DATA HERE'));

});
```